# Fréchet derivative of a operator $E: H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: field-theory, derivatives

Define the operator $E: H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}(u_t^2+u_x^2+\frac{1}{2}(1-u^2)^2)dx,\; \forall \; u \in  H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right),$$
where $L>0$ is a fixed constant.

I want to calculate the Fréchet derivative of $E$, for this I started I started by calculating the Gateaux derivative of $E$: we know that $ E $ is differentiable Gateuax if there is $ f \in  \left(H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right)\right)' $ (dual space) such that, for $u \in H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right),$
$$v_E:=\lim_{\xi \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\xi}\left[E(u+\xi h)-E(u)-f(\xi h)\right]=0,\; \forall \; h \in H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right).$$
I did the math I got to
$$v_E= \int_{0}^{L} (u_t h_t+hu_t+u^3h )\; dx -f(h),$$
but I can’t continue from that point, mainly because I don’t know how to calculate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{L} u_t h_t \; dx.$$
My idea is to calculate the Gateaux derivative (finding such operator $f$) and use the $ E $ continuity to conclude that this derivative coincides with Fréchet's and consequently conclude what I want. How do I proceed?

More details of the space $H_{per}^{1}\left([0,L]\right)$ can be find in [this book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=luiSzIgzQPQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Fourier+Analysis+and+Partial+Differential+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU3fmA7v_oAhX7JrkGHUbiDfcQ6wEIUDAD#v=onepage&q=Fourier%20Analysis%20and%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations&f=false).

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Can you define the space $H_{per}^1([0,L])$? I don't have access to this book.

Comment: @JoãoCaminada I changed the link, see if you can see the definition for it.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno, on which page is it?

Comment: @JoãoCaminada 201.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno, the functional $E$ doesn't make sense. Functions in $H^1_{per}([0,L])$ are functions of a sole variable, while your functional seems to apply to functions of two variables.

Comment: @JoãoCaminada You are right, you are wrong. My question doesn't make sense, sorry for the mistake and inconvenience.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno in other contexts your question makes sense. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @JoãoCaminada It makes sense as long as I consider $E=E (u, u_t) $. Which is an energy of the $\phi^4$ model.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno, in that context could you figure out the proof? If not you should edit your question. I think this is a very interesting question.

Comment: @JoãoCaminada In that context, I think I was able to prove it. Do you think I should explain here how I did it, in that context?

Comment: It's up to you, @GuilhermedeLoreno. In my opinion it is always good when the questions  in this community get answered. It may help others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea what $H^1_{\rm per}[0,L]$ is but it seems to me that  you are making heavy weather of a  simple and standard calculation. Let
$$
E[u]= \frac 1 2\int_0^L (u_t^2+u_x^2 +\frac 12 (1-u^2)^2 dx.
$$
then, with $u(x) \to u(x)+\eta(x)$ we have
$$
\delta E = \int_0^L \left(u_t \eta_t +u_x \eta_x  + (1-u^2)u \eta \right)dx\\
=  \int_0^L \left(-u_{tt} \eta -u_{xx} \eta   + (1-u^2)u \right)\eta(x) dx\\
= \int_0^L (-u_{tt}  -u_{xx}    + (1-u^2)) \eta(x) dx
$$
We have assumed that $\eta(0)=\eta(L)=0$ so as to allow the integration by parts, and so we can read off the  Functional (aka Frechet) derivative to be
$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta u(x)}= \left(-u_{tt}  -u_{xx}   + (1-u^2)u \right).
$$
I think that the restictions on $u$ and $\eta$ do not need to be very strong $u \in C^2[0,L]$ $\eta\in C^1[0,L]$ should suffice for the manipulation to be  legitimate. The extension to the various Banach spaces of Gateaux and Frechet just requires making sure that $\eta$ is in the appropriate dual space.

Comment: What means the simbol $\delta$? For example, what means $\delta E$?

Comment: Whats means $u(x) \rightarrow u(x)+\eta (x)$? And I didn't understand the second equality of $\delta E$.

Comment: The $\delta E$ means "the change in" to $O(||\eta||^2) $accuracy as it always does in calculus. The   Gateaux "directional derivative"  is the change in the functional $E[u]$ under the shift $u(x)\to u(x)+\epsilon \eta(x)$ divided by $\epsilon$. In actual calculation one  never  mentions the $\epsilon$. The calculation is then the usual calculus  variations  manipulations. The distiction between Gataux and Frechet is the same as the distinction between all  partials derivatives existing and the function(al) being differentiable (the latter meaning that there is a local linear approximation).

Comment: The step between the first and second line of my answer is simply integration by parts.

Comment: The derivatives $u_{xx}$ and $u_{tt}$ don't make sense, since $u$ only has one weak derivative.

Comment: @ joão-caminada. Well I said that I did not know what $H^1_{\rm per}$ is.   I thought all distributions has weak derivatives of any order -- although they might not have $|\ldots|^2$  integrals in certain spaces.  The integral in my last line presuamably requires $\eta$ to be a test function in this context.  This question was originally asked in Physics Stack Exchange and  I'm a physicist, so I do not usually have to worry about such technicalities :).

Comment: @mikestone, sorry if my answer seemed harsh, it was not my intention. I was only trying to point out that under the given hypothesis the answer was not correct. I am a mathematician, so I have to worry a lot about such technicalities :). Maybe we are the wrong ones, since, oddly enough, you physicists always arrive at the right answer!

Comment: Hi @João Caminada. No problem with your statement!   But  can  $u$ have a second weak derivative that is somehow not allowed in the $H^1$ space?  I know one-dimnesional Hilbert space stuff resaonably well, but I've never had to use Sobolev spaces. What * is*  $H^1_{\rm per}$?

Comment: $H^1_{per}([0,T])$ is the set of periodic functions on $u: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ that are in $L^2$ and whose first weak derivative is in $L^2$. Thus, functions in $H^1_{per}([0,T])$, without further assumptions, can only be assumed to have one weak derivative. Don't confuse weak derivative with distributional derivative. As a distribution $u$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @João Caminada Ah! I did not know that there was distinction between weak and distributional. I guess it has to do with what is in the dual space $[H^1_{\rm per}]'$ and a suitable  weak topology.

Comment: No. Let me give you the general definition. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Given $u, v \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$, we say that $v$ is the weak $x_i$-partial derivative of $u$ is $\int u(x)\partial_{x_i}\varphi(x)dx = - \int_{\Omega} v(x)\varphi(x)dx$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. So, saying that $u$ has a weak $x_i$-partial derivative is the same as saying that his distributional $x_i$-partial derivative is induced by a function in $L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: Recall that in general, although a 
$L^1_{loc}$ function, always has the distributional partial derivatives of all orders, we cannot assume that this distributional derivatives are induced by $L^1_{loc}$ functions.